# Mann-Whitney U Test and Independent t-test give different results, which to use?

Tags: t-test, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two population and I want to know if the means of the two populations are different. To the best of my knowledge, I should try an Independent t-test if the data is normality distributed and otherwise use the Mann-Whitney U Test, and in most cases, they won't generate different results. Also, I've heard of the Mann-Whitney U Test is sensitive to different in shape, so the histogram is provided, hope this help.
[image]

I first use the Shapiro-Wilk test and confirm that they are not normally distributed (p-value < 1e-10). Then I perform the Brown–Forsythe test to ensure the equal variance as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Alternatives), and turn out we can't reject the null hypothesis (equal variance, p-value=0.48). Then I perform a Mann-Whitney U Test and an independent t-test.

However, the Mann-Whitney U Test give p-value = 2e-25, but the independent t-test give p-value = 0.48, which is not even close.

Why do this happen? Which result should I use? Can I stated that the means are different or not?

Comment: From your histogram it appears that number of observations from two samples may be different. Is it so?

Comment: What was the original (formal) alternative hypothesis of interest? (i.e. what exactly are you trying to find out?)

Comment: @Dayne Yes, the number of observations from two samples are different.

Comment: @Glen_b I like to know if the means of two populations are different.

Comment: Mann Whitney doesn't compare means. You might either choose a more suitable parametric model or you might do a nonparametric test of means. What does your response variable measure?

Comment: @Glen_b Is their any recommended nonparametric test that compare means? 
The textbook I read stated that Mann-Whitney compare the shape of distributions and can therefore used to compare means if the distributions aren't very different.

Comment: Sure; you could do a permutation test of means, for example. Mann Whitney *doesn't* compare shape.